# Separate movies into genre

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a class assignment and we just started on conditionals. For the assignment I'm given a list of movies, and I'm supposed to recommend them by genre. The the user inputs a category they want and a list of the category displays. The only problem is I'm not sure what I have to do to put them in a category.

Lets say we have Deadpool and its an action movie.
Then Frozen which is a family movie.

Would I make my own String calling it Family and Action?

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: There is a rat in separate.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a `Movie` class. If this is the case, I would think you would want a string in that class such as `String genre;`. Then in the main program, you could select movies with `if(movie.genre.equalsIgnoreCase("action")){}` and so on

Answer (score 0):

You may create a Genre enum:

```
public enum Genre {
    ACTION,
    COMEDY,
    HORROR,
    ...
}
```

So you create a genre attribute on Movie class:

```
public class Movie {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Genre genre;
}
```

Then you can get all movies from a category:

```
List<Movie> actionMovies = movies.stream()
    .filter(m -> m.getCategory().equals(Genre.ACTION))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```